# OCaml boolean comparison

Tags: ocaml

I would like to know whether the operators `<` and `>` are defined for boolean values in OCaml? I have a generic function that sorts lists, which should work for boolean lists. I am confused though as to how this sorting should work with boolean lists?

Answer (score 7):

The OCaml `<` and `>` operators are defined for all types except for function types.

For boolean values, false is less than true.

These operators are defined in the [Pervasives](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html) module.  Here is the key documentation:

> These functions coincide with the usual orderings over integers, characters, strings, byte sequences and floating-point numbers, and extend them to a total ordering over all types. The ordering is compatible with ( = ). As in the case of ( = ), mutable structures are compared by contents. Comparison between functional values raises `Invalid_argument`. Comparison between cyclic structures may not terminate.